# Vue instance's $on method is not work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I just created an event bus in the main.js file like this:

### main.js

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue()
```

After that, I just wrote some code to test the event bus like this:

### TestComponent

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div class="account-modal_form">
          <form action="" @submit.prevent="formSubmit">
                <div class="account-modal_form__group" :class="{ warning: errors.has('password') }">
                    <div class="account-modal_form__input">
                        <input name="password" :type="passwordType" placeholder="" class="width-316" v-validate="'required'" v-model="password">
                        <i class="account-modal_form__viewpass" @click="togglePassword"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span class="account-modal_form__warning" v-show="errors.has('password')">
                        {{ errors.first('password') }}
                    </span>
                </div>
                {{ errors }}
                <div class="account-modal_form__group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn--large">next</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn--default" @click="cancelAction">cancel</button>
                </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { API } from '@/api'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            passwordType: 'password',
            password: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        created() {
            this.$bus.$on('test', () => console.log('test'));
        },
        nextStep() {
            this.$bus.$emit('test');
        },
        formSubmit() {
            this.nextStep();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I click submit button I want to submit form first and call nextstep to emit an event, but the $on event output nothing.

Comment: getting any error ? is `Vue.prototype.$bus = ...` done before Vue instance creation ?

Comment: @JacobGoh No, It seems that the sendOriginPassword event is not listened and output nothing. And I try to output this.$bus._event after emit, but it outputs empty.

Answer (score 3):

You're running `$emit` before `$on`, so when you fire the event there are no listeners at that point, and it's better to register your listeners on the component `created` life cycle event, otherwise whenever you run your test method you'll register a new listener:

```js
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();

Vue.component('spy-component', {
  template: '<p>{{this.text}}</p>',
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$bus.$on('sendOriginPassword', (text) => {
      this.text = text;
    });
  }
})

Vue.component('test-component', {
  template: '<button @click="test">Click me</button>',
  created() {
        this.$bus.$on('sendOriginPassword', () => {
      console.log('I am listening event')
    });
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      this.$bus.$emit('sendOriginPassword', 'Can you hear me?');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <spy-component></spy-component>
  <test-component></test-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But if I listen test event in another component's created life cycle it also output nothing, why?

Comment: It should work...I modified example code, check it now.

Comment: I have pasted my code in the question, this time the test event output nothing. I don't know why.

Comment: @ChenLee `created() {}` should be outside `methods`

Comment: Why this.$bus._events contains test event, but if I call this.$bus.$on('test', () => console.log('test')), it output nothing in another component?